# add class to each submenu level of 4-level mega menu

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, nested-lists

My js is pretty rudimentary. I'm building a 4-level mega menu in a WordPress theme (JointsWP framework) and I want each level to be labeled something distinct. Joints already does this for the first submenu, but need the rest to be distinct from each other. what I want:

```
<ul id="main-nav">
    <ul class="first-sub">
         <ul class="second-sub">
            <ul class="third-sub">
```

The best I get:

```
<ul id="main-nav">
    <ul class="first-sub">
         <ul class="second-sub">
            <ul class="second-sub third-sub">
```

I tried to remove the "second-sub" class for the 4th level, I tried to use ">" to just target the second-sub. Both without any luck. Here's what I'm working with so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#main-nav ul ul').addClass('second-sub');
    $('#main-nav ul ul ul').addClass('third-sub');
});
```

I think this is one of those things that's so easy I can't find it in forums, because "duh." Any help appreciated.

Comment: I have not tried may be this should work `$('#main-nav ul:eq(1)').addClass('second-sub');
      $('#main-nav ul:eq(2)').addClass('third-sub');`

Comment: @Swati That assumes there is only one `<ul>` at each level which is unlikely for a mega menu

Comment: @ charlietfl yes you are right ..if op can show proper structure for menus then it would be more  clear currently i am just assuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `not()` for the `second-sub` to exclude any of the descendants

```
$('#main-nav ul ul').not('#main-nav ul ul ul').addClass('second-sub');
$('#main-nav ul ul ul').addClass('third-sub');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop all the children and add classes to it. with this, you can add as many levels as you want. just add the corresponding class name to the array.

```
var classes = ['red', 'blue', 'green']

$('#main-nav').find('*').each(function(index) {
  $(this).addClass(classes[index])
})
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nomansheikh/zqnd786y/1/)

Comment: This is based on invalid markup. Op showed ul nested directly in ul which is pseudo code and is not valid html. They can only be nested inside `<li>`. Your solution using `find('*')` simply will not work